# Maximum value of the sum of absolute values of cubic polynomial coefficients $a,b,c,d$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, optimization, absolute-value

> If $p(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and $|p(x)|\leq 1\forall |x|\leq 1$,  what is the $\max$ value of $|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|$?

**My try:**

- Put $x=0$, we get $p(0)=d$,
- Similarly put $x=1$, we get $p(1)=a+b+c+d$,
- similarly put $x=-1$, we get $p(-1)=-a+b-c+d$,
- similarly put $\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{2}$, we get $\displaystyle p\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{a}{8}+\frac{b}{4}+\frac{c}{2}+d$

So, given that $|p(x)|\leq 1\forall |x|\leq 1$, we get $|d|\leq 1$.

Similarly $$\displaystyle |b|=\left|\frac{p(1)+p(-1)}{2}-p(0)\right|\leq \left|\frac{p(1)}{2}\right|+\left|\frac{p(1)}{2}\right|+|p(0)|\leq 2$$

Now I do  not understand how can I calculate the  $\max$ of $|a|$ and $|c|$.

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ all real?

Comment: Is $x$ only real? The problem seems to be simpler if we can substitute $x=\pm i$

Comment: Yes  Peter Woolfitt $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers.

Comment: $|b+d|\le1$ and $|d|\le 1$. Thus $|b|\le 2$

Comment: Sorry  Virtuoz I have edited my post, actually I  have calculated Max. of  $|b|$

Answer (score 2):

A few simulations made me wonder if the $10$ bound is tight, and I tried to find other ones, as it seems that one could jointly bound the coefficients. I am not able yet to push them to the end, but I propose the first steps. I hope I am not completely wrong.

A  result by V. A. Markov states that:

> If $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m$ and if $|p(x)| \le 1$
>   whenever $-1 \le x \le 1$, then $|p^{(k)}(x)| \le T^{(k)}_m (1)$
>   whenever $-1 \le x \le 1$ and $1 \le k \le m$, with $T_m$ the $m$-th
>   Chebyshev polynomial.

This can be found for instance in [Markov's Inequality for Polynomials on Normed Linear Spaces](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~larry/paper.dir/markov.pdf), L. A. Harris, 2002. From the explicit formula, $T^{(3)}_m (1) = 24$, $T^{(2)}_m (1) = 24$, $T^{(1)}_m (1) = 9$.

We have $p'(x) = 3ax^2+2bx+c$, $p''(x) = 6ax+2b$ and $p'''(x) = 6a$.

For $k=3$,  we get $|6a|\le 24$, hence we recover  $|a|\le 4$.

For $k=2$,  $|6ax+2b| \le 24$. This produces a simplex, along the maxima attained at $x=1$ and  $x=-1$, that reduces the original bounds, since for instance we should have $3a+b\le 12$.

For  $k=1$, this becomes a little more tedious: $|3ax^2+2bx+c|$ reaches its maxima either at $x=1$ (value $|3a+2b+c|$),  $x=-1$  (value $|3a-2b+c|$) or at the apex of the parabola $x=-\frac{b}{3a}$ (value $|c-\frac{b^2}{3a}|$). All these three quantities should be lower than $9$.

These coupled inequalities, together with those given by @Virtuoz, define a volume (non empty, since it contains the Chebyshev  polynomial $T_3(x) =4x^3−3x$) of admissible $(a,b,c)$ triplets.

Courageous wills are now welcome to plug $d$ in and find tighter bounds.

Comment: Did you mean $|p^{(k)}(x)| \le T^{(k)}_m (1)$ instead of $|p^{(k)}(x)|  = T^{(k)}_m (1)$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(1)=u,$ $p(-1)=v$, $p\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=w$ and $p\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=t$.

Thus, we have the following system:
$$a+b+c+d=u,$$
$$-a+b-c+d=v,$$
$$\frac{a}{8}+\frac{b}{4}+\frac{c}{2}+d=w$$ and
$$-\frac{a}{8}+\frac{b}{4}-\frac{c}{2}+d=t,$$ which gives
$$a=\frac{2u-2v-4w+4t}{3},$$
$$b=\frac{2u+2v-2w-2t}{3},$$
$$c=\frac{-u+v+8w-8t}{6}$$ and
$$d=\frac{-u-v+4w+4t}{6}.$$
Now, $$a+b+c+d=u\leq1,$$
$$a+b+c-d=\frac{4u+v-4w-4t}{3}\leq\frac{13}{3},$$
$$a+b-c+d=\frac{4u-v-8w+8t}{3}\leq7,$$
$$a+b-c-d=\frac{5u-12w+4t}{3}\leq7,$$
$$a-b+c+d=\frac{-u-4v+4w+4t}{3}\leq\frac{13}{3},$$
$$a-b+c-d=-v\leq1,$$
$$a-b-c+d=\frac{-5v-4w+12t}{3}\leq7$$ and
$$a-b-c-d=\frac{u-4v-8w+8t}{3}\leq7,$$
which gives
$$|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|\leq7.$$
But for $p(x)=4x^3-3x$ the equality occurs, which says that $7$ is a maximal value.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $x$ is real.

Consider system of four equations with four variables. 
$$
a + b + c + d = p(1),
$$
$$
-a+b-c+d = p(-1),
$$
$$
\frac{a}{8}+\frac{b}{4} + \frac{c}{2} + d = p(1/2),
$$
$$
-\frac{a}{8}+\frac{b}{4} - \frac{c}{2} + d = p(-1/2).
$$
You can just solve it and find values of $a,b,c,d$.

From this equations we get
$$
a+c = \frac{p(1)-p(-1)}{2},
$$
$$
\frac{a}{4} + c = p(1/2) - p(-1/2)
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{3a}{4} = \frac{p(1)-p(-1)}{2} - (p(1/2) - p(-1/2)),
$$
and $|a|\le4$. In the same way we get 
$$
3c = 4(p(1/2) - p(-1/2)) - \frac{p(1)-p(-1)}{2},
$$
and $|c|\le 3$.
The example $T(x) = 4x^3 - 3x$ shows existence of polynomial with $a=4$ and $c=3$.

So, $|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|\le 1 + 2 +3 +4 = 10$, though I don't know if such a polynomial (with $|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|\le 10$ and $p(x)\le 1$) exists.

Comment: Thanks Virtuoz You mean $\displaystyle \frac{a}{4}+c = p\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-p\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: Yes, thank you! I've edited. Fortunately, answer has not changed :)

Comment: Virtuoz Actually answer given is $=7$

Comment: @juantheron That is not a full answer. It just provides en estimate which is not sharp. That's why I wrote in the answer 'don't know if such polynomial exists'. Sorry for misunderstanding, I think this phrase will warn you that the estimate might not be sharp.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\max(|a|,|c|),C=\min(|a|,|c|),B=\max(|b|,|d|),D=\min(|b|,|d|).$ Then $$|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|=|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|.$$
For $|x|\le1$, $|Ax^2-C|\le|ax^2+c|$ and $|Bx^2-D|\le|bx^2+d|$. Then
$$|(A+B)x^3-(C+D)x|\le |Ax^3-Cx|+|Bx^2-D|\le |ax^3+cx|+|bx^2+d|\le |p(x)|\text{ or } |p(-x)|.$$
Therefore we only need consider $p(x)=ax^3-cx$ with $a\ge c\ge0$.

At $x=1$ we need $a\le c+1$ and at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ we need $|a-4c|\le8$. The required maximum is attained for $a=4,c=3$.